# Whats the default Cocos2D schedule interval?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, intervals

In cocos2d when you make a timer with default (blank) interval parameter:

```
 [self schedule:(update)]; 
 //Not a 100% sure this code is correct, but you know what i mean
```

What interval is the timer running at, I think its 1/60, but Im not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your CCDirector setting. If you are using

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
```

or

```
CC_DIRECTOR_INIT();
```

then update method is invoked every 1/60 second.